# SSRS Local Mode ReportViewer control Scheduling reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

This is regarding reports produced by ReportViewer control in Asp.Net
I need to schedule reports to run at specified times , intervals. This information is set up in database tables and the reports have to be run using the reportviewer control as background jobs. I can think of having a Webpage with the reportviewer control Up and the page polling the schedule table and running the required reports. But it is inconvenient to keep the page running so wondering if there is any way to do it as a batch job in the background

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the server and not just the webserver, I would suggest writting some vbscripts or equivalent that call .rss files to run your reports. You can then schedule them in windows schedule and have them save to a directory, email or even print (although printing is more difficult, I use ghostscript). This link has a pretty good description of the process: [How to automate Report Deployment using SSRS Web Service](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3889376/How-to-Automate-Report-Deployment-Using-SSRS-Web-Service.htm)

Comment: Hi Steve my report is Local mode report using the reportviewer control .It does not really use reporting services. How can I automate these

Comment: Can you post example code of how you call/open the report in reportviewer? Do you have a .rdl file? Do you have an SSRS server?